# how I can write two links that go to the same page with different jobs?

Tags: php, html

The first page has two Hyperlinks:

```
<p> COE  <a href="page2.php">here</a></p>
<p> SWE <a href="page2.php">here</a></p>
```

What I'd like is: when a user clicks on the first link, page2 should display this link:

```
<p> academic transcript  <a href="A.php">here</a></p>
```

and when a user clicks on the second link, page2 will display a different link which is :

```
<p> courses list  <a href="B.php">here</a></p>
```

Can I do that??

Comment: It is not quite clear what you are asking. English seems to be not your first language. Perhaps a friend can help making your question more clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to separate the two links in some way. You can pass a `$_GET` parameter on, and check if it's set or not on your second page.

If you edit your hyperlinks to the following

```
<p>COE <a href="page2.php?page=A">here</a></p>
<p>SWE <a href="page2.php?page=B">here</a></p>
```

we can then use `$_GET` in PHP to find the value of the parameter `page` in your URL, like below. The comments should explain more or less what's going on.

```
if (!empty($_GET['page'])) {
    // If that parameter is set, we can check what it's set to
    switch($_GET['page']) {
        case "A":
            // If the value was A, we display this
            echo '<p>academic transcript <a href="A.php">here</a></p>';
            break;
        case "B":
            // If the value was B, we display this 
            echo '<p>courses list <a href="B.php">here</a></p>';
            break;
        default:
            // It didn't match any of the values, you can display a default page
            echo "Not a valid page";
    }
} else {
    // You can put whatever you want here, 
    // but if no values of ?page= is set, whatever is inside here will be displayed
    echo "Nothing to show!";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your main page add this:

```
<p> COE  <a href="page2.php?pageA">here</a></p>
<p> SWE <a href="page2.php?pageB">here</a></p>
```

And in page2.php add this:

```
$url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];   

if (strpos($url,'pageA') !== false) {
    echo '<p> academic transcript  <a href="A.php">here</a></p>';
} elseif (strpos($url,'pageB') !== false) {
    echo '<p> courses list  <a href="B.php">here</a></p>';
}
```

What's happening above is PHP is checking for whether or not `pageA` or `pageB` is passed as an argument the modifying the page respectively to handle either event.